# Understanding max on

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently learning Python as a student, but I can't seem to grasp the idea of dictionary.

Let's say

```
d = {'I': 1, ' ': 2, 'P': 1, 'L': 1, 'E': 3, 'H': 1, 'D': 1, 'N': 1}
```

I want to to use the function `max` to return the key which has the highest value.

```
max (d.values(), key = lambda x: x[0])
```

But I get an error which say

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `d.values()` returns the dictionaries *values*, which are integers. You can't subscript those.

Comment: You're indexing the integers. Checkout the duplicate for an appropriate way .

Comment: since d.values() returns a list, you can simply just get the maximum value of the list max(d.values()). You're currently trying to index an integer, which you can't do!

Comment: You can also use `[k for k in d.keys() if d[k] == max(d.values())][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking `max()` to get the maximum *value*, because you passed in `d.values()`. Each of those values is an `int` object, so you can't do `x[0]` on those.

Pass in the dictionary itself, and as the `key`, use `d.get`. Iteration over that object produces keys, and `max()` will find the key based on what `d.get(k)` returns:

```
max(d, key=d.get)
```